# GSON returning Exception json syntax exception expected a string but was begin_object at line 1 column 15

Tags: android, json, gson

Below is my code. While i am running it shows "json syntax exception expected a string but was begin_object". I don't know why it shows the error.

```
 {
"products": [
    {
        "name": "gam",
        "pplsft": "75665",
        "imei": "Ptwm ",
        "created_at": "2012-12-03 04:58:01"
    },
    {
        "name": "",
        "pplsft": "0",
        "imei": "",
        "created_at": "2012-12-03 05:44:01"
    },
    {
        "name": "gptw",
        "pplsft": "0",
        "imei": "at",
        "created_at": "2012-12-03 05:58:18"
    },
    {
        "name": "",
        "pplsft": "0",
        "imei": "",
        "created_at": "2012-12-03 23:32:06"
    },
    {
        "name": "",
        "pplsft": "0",
        "imei": "",
        "created_at": "2012-12-03 23:35:25"
    }
]
}
```

and the class file are, but i dont know exactly how to create the class file for json parsing using gson. Can anobdy explain this??

```
  public class Results  {
public String name;
@SerializedName("pplsft")
public int pplsft;
@SerializedName("imei")
public String imei;
@SerializedName("created_at")
public int created_at;
     }

   public class SearchResponse  {

@SerializedName("products")
public List<Result> products;
@SerializedName("name")
public String name;
@SerializedName("pplsft")
public int pplsft;
@SerializedName("imei")
public String imei;
@SerializedName("created_at")
public int created_at;
public List<Result> getProducts() {
    return products;
}
public void setProducts(List<Result> products) {
    this.products = products;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getPplsft() {
    return pplsft;
}
public void setPplsft(int pplsft) {
    this.pplsft = pplsft;
}
public String getImei() {
    return imei;
}
public void setImei(String imei) {
    this.imei = imei;
}
public int getCreated_at() {
    return created_at;
}
public void setCreated_at(int created_at) {
    this.created_at = created_at;
}

   }
```

This is the main method for calling the data from the json.

```
    response = gson.fromJson(reader, SearchResponse.class);
Toast.makeText(this,response.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
List<Result> list = response.products;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object should be as follows for JSON:

```
SearchResponse response = gson.fromJson(reader, SearchResponse.class);
```

Then to get your list:

```
List<Product> mProducts = response.products;
```

To go through your list you do the following:

```
for( Product pro : mProducts ){
    String pName = pro.name;
    ......
}
```

or you can just do it manually(get name from the first object;

```
mProducts.get(0).name;
```

Now your class:

```
public class SearchResponse  {

    @SerializedName("products")
    public List<Product> products;

    public class Product {

        @SerializedName("name")     
        public String name;

        @SerializedName("pplsft")
        public String pplsft;

        @SerializedName("imei")
        public String imei;

        @SerializedName("created_at")
        public String created_at;

    }
}
```

your JSON

```
{
   "products":[
      {
         "name":"gam",
         "pplsft":"75665",
         "imei":"Ptwm ",
         "created_at":"2012-12-03 04:58:01"
      },
      {
         "name":"",
         "pplsft":"0",
         "imei":"",
         "created_at":"2012-12-03 05:44:01"
      },
      {
         "name":"gptw",
         "pplsft":"0",
         "imei":"at",
         "created_at":"2012-12-03 05:58:18"
      },
      {
         "name":"",
         "pplsft":"0",
         "imei":"",
         "created_at":"2012-12-03 23:32:06"
      },
      {
         "name":"",
         "pplsft":"0",
         "imei":"",
         "created_at":"2012-12-03 23:35:25"
      }
   ]
}
```

[Perhaps the Solution to this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484353/gson-throws-malformedjsonexception) could be of some help to you as well.

Comment: But now i got an error like "jsonsyntaxexception malformed Json Exception expected EOF at line 2 column 1"

Comment: How are you generating this JSON? Is it a feed or are you generating it locally? Make sure there arent any hidden characters.

Comment: yes it is having hidden character..thanks. I have one more question. How can get only one value?..like "product.name"