# setLenient(true) Error while parsing with Gson Library

Tags: java, json, gson

My Sample Json Array :

```
{ 
 "tag":{
    "id": "1112",
    "AP": "77",
    "data":[
       {
         "name": "position",
         "type": "integer",
         "unit": "meter",
         "value": 5
       },
       {
         "type": "RSSI",
         "unit": "dBm",
         "value": -76
       }
     ]
   }
}
```

And This is My Code :

```
public void parse(){
    String json = new String(inPacket.getData());
    JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(json);
    JsonObject  jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
}
```

And Exception Code :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" 
    com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 
    com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: 
    Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 154
      at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:65)
      at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:45)
```

I Dont know about JSON array. But Google Gson library is can help me.
How Can I Fix this Problem? Would you please help me?

Comment: That JSON works fine for me. Are you sure that's what `inPacket.getData()` contains?

Comment: It seems your line 1 doesn't have column 154. Can you print out the String `json`. I suspect the `new String(inPacket.getData)` does not give you what you were expecting.

Comment: Maybe you have invisible characters. Investigate that because the JSON as you've shown it will not cause the error you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks All! @SotiriosDelimanolis String.trim() methode fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIX :: Use String.trim() Method. And This Code is working.

```
public void parse(){
    String json = new String(inPacket.getData());
    JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(json.trim());
    JsonObject  jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
}
```

Comment: Very useful. This is discussed in more details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484353/gson-throws-malformedjsonexception

Answer (score 7):

If the trim() doesn't work, you can use setLenient:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(myFooString));
reader.setLenient(true);
JsonParser.parseReader(reader)
```

Comment: To avoid the 2 'deprecated' warnings on `new JsonParser().parse(reader)`, you can use the static methods: `JsonParser.parseReader(reader)`