# Getting data from a server with BasicValuePairName?

Tags: php, android, json, get

I'm using a JSONParser class to create JSON to be sended to the server, but I need to use it for receive information now, but I don't know how to do it, I'm a noob, sorry. I create the json with the next part of code, and the following class.

```
// Building Parameters
            params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", thought.getUser()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timestamp", "" + thought.getTimestamp()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", thought.getMessage()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", thought.getAddress()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", "" + thought.getLatitude()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", "" + thought.getLongitude()));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_thought, "POST", params);
```

**JSONParser.class**

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method.equalsIgnoreCase("POST")){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method.equalsIgnoreCase("GET")){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

The part in the server I think that it's ok.

**Server get values part**

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM thoughts") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["thoughts"] = array();

    echo '<center><div class="datagrid"><table>';
    echo '<thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>USERID</th><th>TIMESTAMP</th><th>MESSAGE</th><th>ADDRESS</th><th>LATITUDE</th><th>LONGITUDE</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $thought = array();
        $thought["id"] = $row["id"];
        $thought["userid"] = $row["userid"];
        $thought["timestamp"] = $row["timestamp"];
        $thought["message"] = $row["message"];
        $thought["address"] = $row["address"];
        $thought["latitude"] = $row['latitude'];
        $thought["longitude"] = $row['longitude'];

        echo '<tr><td>'.$row['id'].'</td><td>'.$row['userid'].'</td><td>'.$row['timestamp'].'</td><td>'.$row['message'].'</td><td>'.$row['address'].'</td><td>'.$row['latitude'].'</td><td>'.$row['longitude'].'</td></tr>';

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["thoughts"], $thought);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    //echo json_encode($response);
    echo '</table></center>';
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No events found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

What it's the correct way to get data in android?? What I need to put in params?

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_thought, **"GET"**, params);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: May i please ask you to post your server response. Because I think your server code is not correct. The reason I am saying this is when receiving json response you should 'ONLY' echo json response and nothing else. your code should only use `echo json_encode($response)` nothing else should echoed. you are using `echo` for table and some other stuff which will create error in json format.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple way to get what u want from json-return url :

```
String sURL = "http://freegeoip.net/json/"; //just a string

// Connect to the URL using java's native library
URL url = new URL(sURL);
HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
request.connect();

// Convert to a JSON object to print data
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //convert the input stream to a json element
JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //may be an array, may be an object. 
zipcode=rootobj.get("zipcode").getAsString();//just grab the zipcode
```

Comment: did u import "com.google.gson.JsonElement" jar file ?
download it from here :
https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list

Comment: No. I'm going to import it now. I will comment the results.

Comment: JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
            

"request" cannot be resolved. Some other library? thanks

Comment: u create instance of request with this command : "HttpURLConnection request". is it created properly ? if not check HttpURLConnection have imported properly. also this is core of android api. no need to import third party jar for this one

Comment: MalFormedJSON exception... :s

Comment: Is there a way to view the returned data?

Comment: @Victor_J_Martin before you pass the response to json class convert it to string and use log to view it. and if possible post it here as well.

Comment: I'm doing... Log.i("IO", request.getContent().toString()); but It shows me I/IO﹕ libcore.net.http.FixedLengthInputStream@42aee070

Comment: @Victor_J_Martin i think there is some problem with ur json string.
check this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484353/gson-throws-malformedjsonexception