# Convert array-like String to ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, arraylist, gson

I've been trying to convert a String like this: "[1,2,3]" to an ArrayList in Java. 
What I tried so far is to use GSon library to convert the String mentioned above to List using:

1. [Gson - convert from Json to a typed ArrayList<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384064/gson-convert-from-json-to-a-typed-arraylistt)
2. [Convert Gson Array to Arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042809/convert-gson-array-to-arraylist)
3. [Parsing JSON array into java.util.List with Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544133/parsing-json-array-into-java-util-list-with-gson)

but it ends with an exception (I can provide more details if needed). The first question should be actually if it's a good approach to achieve such a transformation?

Comment: *The first question should be actually if it's a good approach to achieve such a transformation?*  Yes, it's fine. *but it ends with an exception (I can provide more details if needed).* Please do.

Comment: You could cut the brackets away [ ] and split the string by the coma. 
Something like: 
String employee = "Smith,Katie,3014,,8.25,6.5,,,10.75,8.5";
String delims = "[,]";
String[] tokens = employee.split(delims); 
The tokens array then could be easily converted to an arraylist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-regex method would be to remove the brackets from the string and then split on the commas. Then convert to an ArrayList.

```
String s = "[1, 2, 3]";
String[] splits =  s.replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",");
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(splits));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use regular expression to convert the string from "[1,2,3,...]" to "1,2,3,..." and then ue asList() method of Arrays class to convert it to a List.

Refer the following snippet

```
import java.util.regex.*;
...
...
String str = "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]";
str = str.replaceAll("[(*)])","$1");
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```