# Retrofit post single and JsonArray parameters

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-json

Json data:

```
{
"userId":"5",
"name" : "mahdi",
"family" : "pishguy",
"id" : [{"1":"2333"},{"2":"12"},{"3":"123"}],
"token" : "10"
}
```

and I'm trying post with this code:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("rst_store")
Call<User> saveUser(@Body User User);

Call<User> call = myService.saveUserSeeks(User);
call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<User> call, final Response<User> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
        if (t.getMessage() != null) Log.e("Err: ", t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

I get this error:

```
Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
```

How can I resolve this problem?

thank you.

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: @MithileshGupta `Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $`

Comment: change `private int   code;` to `private Integer code;` or ignore it like this `private transient  int  code;`

Comment: see this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35984898/retrofit2-0-gets-malformedjsonexception-while-the-json-seems-correct

Comment: Where do you get that error? Post the full stack trace.