# Android Studio suddenly crashes at startup

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

I have not used Android Studio 2.3.2 for 3 or 4 days and suddenly I have got the error below when I try to launch it. Note that I installed separately Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1 one week ago but everything was ok and both versions worked without problems. I don't understand why I suddenly have a problem to launch Android Studio.

I use a MacBook.

Here is the error log given by Android Studio at launch:

```
Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:203)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.lambda$null$0(MainImpl.java:47)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:358)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:248)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:536)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$createComponents$8(ApplicationImpl.java:429)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$3.run(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:494)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:443)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:155)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:436)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:103)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:384)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:196)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 9 column 2 path $
    at com.google.gson.Gson.assertFullConsumption(Gson.java:837)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:827)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.PlatformTarget.getLibsFromJson(PlatformTarget.java:179)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.PlatformTarget.<init>(PlatformTarget.java:124)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.AndroidTargetManager.getTargetMap(AndroidTargetManager.java:94)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.AndroidTargetManager.getTargets(AndroidTargetManager.java:80)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.AndroidTargetManager.getTargetFromHashString(AndroidTargetManager.java:154)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData.findTargetByHashString(AndroidSdkData.java:216)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkAdditionalData.getBuildTarget(AndroidSdkAdditionalData.java:126)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidPlatform.parse(AndroidPlatform.java:90)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkAdditionalData.getAndroidPlatform(AndroidSdkAdditionalData.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidPlatform.getInstance(AndroidPlatform.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.GradleSpecificInitializer.checkAndSetSources(GradleSpecificInitializer.java:459)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.GradleSpecificInitializer.checkAndSetAndroidSdkSources(GradleSpecificInitializer.java:449)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.GradleSpecificInitializer.run(GradleSpecificInitializer.java:121)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.activateAndroidStudioInitializerExtensions(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:198)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.<init>(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:220)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:495)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 9 column 2 path $
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1574)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1423)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:546)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:429)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.assertFullConsumption(Gson.java:833)
    ... 54 more
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Check your json response, may it has some problem.

Comment: Do you use Retrofit?

Comment: No, I don't use Retrofit. @PratikButani : what do you mean by 'check your json response' ? Thanks.

Comment: Your logcat saying that `Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON` that means you may have to refer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36002007/1318946

Comment: Thanks but it seems that the problem is not in my app but linked to Android Studio itself which crashes after the initial startup window/splash screen (when the loading bar reaches 100%). The code in my app has certainly nothing to do with this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed the problem.

What I have done:

- close Android Studio
- go to /users/your_name/library/preferences
- rename the folder 'AndroidStudio2.3' to 'AndroidStudio2.3XXX' (or whatever :))
- restart Android Studio
- As my Android SDK was in located in an unusual folder, Android Studio asked me if I want to tell where is my SDK (choosing this option did not solve the problem) or install it at the default Android Studio location ; I chose this last option and it solved the issue !

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar issue posted on Androids open source bug tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74458

The solution was to restart your computer. Try this and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Restarting did not help :(

Answer (score 0):

I had that crash too. I guess it was due to the upload of the last project. so to prevent that upload I moved it from the androidstudioprojects folder which is where all the projects are stored,and it solved the problem-the studio initialized well. but after  that I brought the project back to that folder and opened it from the studio,and it was crashed again. since I have another newer version of android studio, I used it to open that project. after it finished the whole process (indexing,building etc) I closed that project and tried again to open from the first version of the studio and it succeeded.
I guess last time I worked with that project I closed it not well (through task manager) and it affected something.