# GSON - Json Parsing Error

Tags: java, json

```
try{            
    JsonElement rawJson =
            GsonUtils.JsonParser.parse(new InputStreamReader(
                new URL("http://api.mineplex.com/pc/player/abc?apiKey=1")
                  .openConnection().getInputStream()));

     }catch(JsonIOException | JsonSyntaxException | IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and

```
public class GsonUtils
{
    public static Gson gson = new Gson();
    public static Gson prettyGson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting()
        .create();
    public static JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
}
```

were the classes I used to get the JSON and parse it. But when I run the first one, it reports the following stacktrace:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 2 column 2
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:65)
...
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 2 column 2
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1505)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1386)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:531)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:414)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:60)
    ... 13 more
```

It tells me to add `JsonReader.setLenient(true)` to my code but my code doesn't use JsonReader. Then how can I add `setLenient(true)` to my code?

EDIT: Add API response (formatted):

```
{
  "statusCode": 401,
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "Invalid API Key. To get an api key use the /api command in game"
}
```

Comment: Can you post the text your code is receiving from the API call?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gson throws MalformedJsonException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484353/gson-throws-malformedjsonexception)

Comment: That's weird. It seems to be perfectly valid JSON; are you sure that this is exactly what is being fed to GSON?

Comment: Are you sure there are no extraneous characters after the input? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11488385/679240

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be over complicating the use of the GSON library.  The following code snippet works fine for me locally in IntelliJ:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String input = "{\"statusCode\": 401, error\": \"Unauthorized\", \"message\": \"Invalid API Key. To get an api key use the /api command in game\"}";
JsonElement json = gson.fromJson(input, JsonElement.class);
System.out.println(json.toString());
```

Here I have used the overloaded version of `Gson.fromJson()` which takes a string, but there is also a version which takes a `FileReader`.

In your case, you might try this:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(
            new URL("http://api.mineplex.com/pc/player/abc?apiKey=1")
              .openConnection().getInputStream()));
JsonElement json = gson.fromJson(reader, JsonElement.class);
// use your JsonElement here
```

Comment: Both of which would have a bit of an overhead, since you would have to either convert it to an String first, or save it to disk first.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK I'm updating now with a solution more applicable to the OP.

Comment: Okay, using an Reader (non-FileReader) seems to be a good option.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nice answer! Also how can I convert it to JsonObject without declaring another variable?

Comment: Maybe you can call `json.getAsJsonObject()` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `JsonObject jsonObject1 = json1.getAsJsonObject();` causes `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: "<html>"
 at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonObject(JsonElement.java:90).......
`

Comment: Please open a new question, this isn't a good way to get further help.  Reference this question if you want to.