# Android Studio MalformedJsonException

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, gson

Just today I was on Android Studio working on a project, when my computer suddenly crashed in the middle of an upload.
Ever since I rebooted it, the Gradle Console has been returning this same error:

> com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use
>   JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column
>   1

I cannot make any sense out of this error, and could not find anyone else with the same issue. They always tend to differ in weird ways, and none of them are the error I have. I have not edited any of the JSON files (because I don't know where they are located).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gson throws MalformedJsonException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484353/gson-throws-malformedjsonexception)

Comment: @maveň That assumes the problem exists in some JSON code the OP claims to have never touched

Comment: @Bryson, please show the full stacktrace.

Comment: @cricket_007 better to ask OP for more clarification then.

Comment: @cricket_007 I would, but the issue mysteriously fixed itself when I was away. It no longer returns the error, so I am led to believe it works again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clean your project using :

Go to **Build -> Clean Project**

Then Rebuild again using :

Go to **Build -> Rebuild Project**

I hope it might help you !

Comment: That doesn't still seems correct, maybe downvoted in future

Comment: read my comment in the question and delete your answer.. since its irrespective from what OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

> File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

you can try this

Answer (score 1):

### Firebase android Projects,

If you are using Firebase in your Mobile app.

download the google-services.json file and put it inside the /app folder and run the project again.