# Bad Request from Jersey server endpoint

Tags: java, json, jersey, gson, payara

I've been looking at a problem which happens when I submit a request;

```
X-Forwarded-For: so.me.ip.ad
Authorization: Bearer blahblahblahstuff
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_60
Host: the.endpoint.io
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 395
```

with a syntactically correct Gson json body. It's exactly the same length, and well formed. I used wireshark to capture the exact response and the numbers add up. ie, I don't think there's bloat on the end of the request body. Please tell me if wireshark wouldn't be able to pick this up. Considering this, I don't think the fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484353/gson-throws-malformedjsonexception) would be applicable to this issue.

I've been testing it locally running payara, and the production server is also payara (exact same version). Locally, the request is fine, works as expected, using exactly the same params live, the endpoint isn't reached, as we handle our own api error codes, and this one is given in html, not json, and can be seen below;

> Payara Server 
>   4.1.2.173 #badassfish - Error report
>
> ## HTTP
>   Status 400 - Bad Request
>
> ---
>
> **type:**  Status
>   report
>
> **message:** Bad Request
>
> **description:** The
>   request sent by the client was syntactically
>   incorrect.
>
> ---
>
> #### Payara Server  4.1.2.173
>   #badassfish

We are using the HttpUrlConnection library execute the post;

```
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        if (this.clientip != null && !this.clientip.isEmpty())
        {
            connection.addRequestProperty("X-Forwarded-For", this.clientip);
        }
        if (this.vauthtoken != null && !this.vauthtoken.isEmpty())
        {
            connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.vauthtoken);
        }
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        connection.setRequestMethod(this.method);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        if(this.body != null)
        {
            try (OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream()) {
                os.write(this.body.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
            }
        }

        if(connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            response = this.getJsonBody(connection.getInputStream());
        }
        else
        {
            response = this.getJsonBody(connection.getErrorStream());
        }
```

And our endpoint looks like;

```
@Path("/some/path")
public class SomeClass extends SomeThingelse {

    final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SomeClass.class.getName());

    @POST
    @Audit
    @Secured(roles = {Role.SOMEROLE}, crud = Crud.CREATE)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response someMethodRelating(@Context SecurityContext securityContext, @Valid SomeValidatedClass svClass)
    {
```

Have I missed something? Or is this more of a server issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you are not using the correct method (using GET instead of POST), or the body you are sending is not JSON or does not validate the rules that are in `SomeValidatedClass`.

Comment: but surely that would be apparent running it locally? All of the above are correct in my code, and the json body I validated from wireshark with JSONLint

Comment: Ok then, considering you use your own API error code, there is also the possibility that you redirect to an error page when you get an error in the method (say you redirect to "/error"), if you do this the request that will go to the handler that is responsible for returning the error (the controller of "/error") will be POST as well, which might not be accepted. (tell me if it's not that I might have other ideas)

Comment: One of the values for @Valid wasn't actually valid, and because of this answer, I worked it out. So thanks! Now just have to work out why we weren't getting the appropriate error messages. Cheers