# GSON Convert to Java POJO

Tags: java, json, gson

I have following input JSON string which I want to convert to JSON Object.

```
{
  "myId": "SN001",
  "field2": "PM4334",
  "field3": "76.99",
  "field4": "2.0",
  "values": "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
}
```

However I am getting following error while conversion using Gson library in my Java program.

```
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected ':' at line 1 column 150 path $.1
```

Requesting you to help me in this case.

Additional details

```
String inputMsg = inputMsgObj.toString();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().serializeNulls().create();
DeviceMessage msg = gson.fromJson(inputMsg, DeviceMessage.class);
```

Getting the error message at third line while converting the message to DeviceMessage

Comment: Please share the code. That would help to analyse.

Comment: Is values supposed to be a string or should it be an array of numbers?

Comment: I believe your question [was answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484353/gson-throws-malformedjsonexception)

Comment: I doubt the JSON you shared is the actual string you are parsing, as the one you provided is valid and the error says you are missing a colon (`:`).

Comment: Hi Polywhir, The JSON is valid and if I remove other values in "values" element and keep only "0", it works. If I add the values like "0,1" then it gives me error.

Comment: Hi mwarren, the expected input is the string from the source and that is comma separated.

Comment: @berkoab, thanks for your suggestion. With this I am able to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes. I was able to resolve the issue by following the details given in link